# Server is not getting started after adding WebServlet annotation

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets

It is a login form using an excel file as database. A jsp  page with form and a servlet page is created. When servlet annotation is given in the servlet page, the server is not getting started.

I am using Eclipse photon and tomcat 9.xxx server. Also added apache poi jar files in the library. If we comment @WebServlet("xxxx") the server gets started. There is no web.xml file is created.

```
@WebServlet("/validateLogin")
public class validateLogin extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

    try {
        doGet(request, response);

        response.setContentType("text/html");
        PrintWriter write=response.getWriter();
        String username = request.getParameter("Username");
        String password = request.getParameter("Password");

        FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(new File("userData.xlsx"));
        XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(file);
        Sheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
        Iterator<Row> rowIterator = sheet.iterator();

        while (rowIterator.hasNext()) {

            // Next row.
            Row row = rowIterator.next();

            // Get column records.
            Cell column1 = row.getCell(0);
            Cell column2 = row.getCell(1);

            // Read records.
            if (column1 != null && column2 != null) {

                String recordUsername = ""; 
                String recordPassword = "";

                if (column1.getCellType().toString().contains("STRING")) {
                    recordUsername = column1.getStringCellValue();
                } else if (column1.getCellType().toString().contains("NUMERIC")) {
                    recordUsername = Integer.toString((int)column1.getNumericCellValue());
                }

                if (column2.getCellType().toString().contains("STRING")) {
                    recordPassword = column2.getStringCellValue();
                } else if (column2.getCellType().toString().contains("NUMERIC")) {
                    recordPassword = Integer.toString((int)column2.getNumericCellValue());
                }


                if (username.equals(recordUsername) && password.equals(recordPassword)) {

                    RequestDispatcher rd=request.getRequestDispatcher("logged.jsp");
                    rd.forward(request, response); 
                } else {
                    write.print("Invalid");
                    RequestDispatcher rd=request.getRequestDispatcher("viewLogin.jsp");
                    rd.include(request, response); 

               }
            }  

            }

        file.close();
        workbook.close();    
        write.close();
           }
    catch(NullPointerException e) {
        System.out.println(e);  

    }
    catch(FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
    catch(IOException e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
```

When trying to start server it shows Server encountered with a problem and faild to start.

Comment: Is there a stacktrace in your tomcat logs?

Comment: Would you please share what the error log says?

Comment: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/Example]]

Comment: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Sheet

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34413/why-am-i-getting-a-noclassdeffounderror-in-java

Comment: But how can I overcome it?

Comment: create a web.xml file and add it to your WEB-INF folder... make sure you're using at least version servlets 3.1 in project configuration

Comment: Is web.xml is required while using servlet annotation. I'm using Tomcat 9.xx.

Comment: Its not working even after creating web.xml file.